# Is the occurrence of an event accelerating

Tags: acceleration, velocity, frequency, speed

Say you have a frequently occurring event and you have measured the intervals between the occurrences in seconds. (so have a dataset that looks like [4, 6, 9, 13] for example).

What formula(s) would you use to determine if the event occurrences were accelerating or increasing in frequency?

One solution I have considered is to take samples of the dataset and sum the values - if the sum of a later set is less than the sum of an earlier set then this would imply that an increase in frequency had occurred. However, I'm interested to know if there is a better or more elegant solution, like a series based formula.

Comment: I don't see how the original question was unclear enough to close, *especially* without even bothering to comment *what* is unclear about the question in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is one of the simpler applications of [time series analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series).

I would just graph each event time against the event number, i.e. the points for your data would be:

$$(1,4) \\ (2,6) \\ (3,9) \\ (4,13) $$

then if the data is well fitted by a straight line you know the event frequency is not changing.

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm looking for is a formula the can give me a numerical indication of acceleration based on a series input.

Comment: @LukeHaas: Just fit a polynomial to the time series.